# SolrTemplate.delete(SolrDataQuery query) not working

Tags: sql, solr

I try to delete from solr with a query. My query looks like: MODIFIED_DATE:[* TO 1504094035082]. If I make a select with this query it returns a result. I also tried to delete with:

```
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/core");
client.deleteByQuery("MODIFIED_DATE:[* TO 1504094035082]");

client.commit();
client.close();
```

and it works. But I need to do with SolrTemplate. Any idea why this

```
    SolrDataQuery dataQuery = new SimpleQuery("MODIFIED_DATE:[* TO 1504094035082]");
    comparerSolrTemplate.delete(dataQuery);
```

is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find my answer. I used a SimpleStringCriteria in SimpleQuery and a commit:

```
SolrDataQuery dataQuery = new SimpleQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria(SolrEntitiesFieldsIF.MODIFIED_DATE_FIELD + ":[* TO " + (new Date().getTime() - 60 * 10000) + "]"));
comparerSolrTemplate.delete(dataQuery);
comparerSolrTemplate.commit();
```